# ASP.Net/JQuery: PLUploader "Add Files" will not fire after uploading images

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi i have been using PLUploader controller for asp.net c#. It works as intended (it would appear at first) but once i have uploaded my files the controler disables the "add files" button (or the button does not work) and i am unable to add more images.

Can anybody help? I have posted the code below that i think the error appears in but if any other code is needed just ask an i will edit the post.

Thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                        // Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
                        var initUploader = function () {
                            $("#uploader").plupload({
                                // General settings
                                runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
                                url: '/Account/Upload.ashx',

                                // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
                                //max_file_count: 10,

                                chunk_size: '1mb',

                                // Resize images on clientside if we can
                                resize: {
                                    width: 800,
                                    height: 600,
                                    quality: 90,
                                    crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
                                },

                                multiple_queues: true,

                                filters: {
                                    // Maximum file size
                                    max_file_size: '10mb',
                                    // Specify what files to browse for
                                    mime_types: [
                                    { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png,jpeg" },
                                    { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
                                    ]
                                },

                                // Resize images on clientside if we can
                                resize: { width: 800, height: 600, quality: 90 },

                                // Rename files by clicking on their titles
                                rename: true,

                                // Sort files
                                sortable: true,

                                // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
                                dragdrop: true,

                                // Views to activate
                                views: {
                                    list: true,
                                    thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
                                    active: 'thumbs'
                                },

                                // Flash settings
                                flash_swf_url: '/App_Themes/js/Moxie.swf',

                                // Silverlight settings
                                silverlight_xap_url: '/App_Themes/js/Moxie.xap',

                                init: {
                                    UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                                        // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed
                                        up.destroy();
                                        initUploader();
                                        UploadComplete();
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                            // Handle the case when form was submitted before uploading has finished
                            $('#form').submit(function (e) {
                                // Files in queue upload them first
                                if ($('#uploader').plupload('getFiles').length > 0) {

                                    // When all files are uploaded submit form
                                    $('#uploader').on('complete', function () {
                                        $('#form')[0].submit();
                                    });

                                    $('#uploader').plupload('start');
                                } else {
                                    alert("You must have at least one file in the queue.");
                                }
                                return false; // Keep the form from submitting


                            });
                        };

    function UploadComplete() {

        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= _imagesButton.ClientID %>");
                            clickButton.click();

                        }

        $(document).ready(function () { initUploader(); });
        up.refresh();
                    </script>

                    <p>Please ensure you upload ALL photos at the same time, you may only press start upload ONCE, thanks.</p>

                    <div id="uploader" style="width: 100%!important;">
                        <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

how are you?

I think the problem is this part of the code:

```
 UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                                    // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed
                                    up.destroy();
                                    initUploader();
                                    UploadComplete();
                                }
```

I think you should use:

```
 UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                                    // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed
                                    up.splice();
                                    up.refresh();
                                    UploadComplete();
                                }
```

And in the $.ready, you should remove: "up.refresh()".